# Add text into textarea on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got this mark-up which for the most part works (jQuery required):

```
<label>Description</label><br />
<textarea id="the-text"></textarea>   
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" id="get-alternative-text">Use alternative text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#get-alternative-text").click(function(){
     $("#the-text").text("this is the alternative text").show();
});
</script>
```

If you click the 'Use alternative text' link then the alternative text gets thrown into the text area. But this only works if the user hasn't already put content into the textarea.

I need it to work so that even if the textarea is already populated, then clicking the 'Use alternative text' link will replace everything that is currently in the textarea.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `text` to `val`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lyybef/

```
$("#get-alternative-text").click(function () {
    $("#the-text").val("this is the alternative text").show();
});
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks for that. Can't believe I forgot about val.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for setting `textarea` value instead of `.text()`:

```
 $("#get-alternative-text").click(function(){
      $("#the-text").val("this is the alternative text");
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knrspx8e/).

Answer (score 0):

Textarea have no value attribute, use `text()` or `html()`.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/don/knrspx8e/1/

**jQuery:**

```
$("#get-alternative-text").click(function(){
     $("#the-text").text("this is the alternative text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it should be

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/qb3vwxLk/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#get-alternative-text").click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#the-text").val("this is the alternative text");
    });


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("#get-alternative-text").click(function(){
   var txt = $.trim($('#the-text').val());
   if(txt.length==0)
   {
     $("#the-text").attr('value', "this is the alternative text");
   }
 });
```